# Redirect to an action in controller doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code :

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            if (dbcontext.SettingConfs.First().offlineState == "true")
            {

                TempData["Error"] = "ژمان ثبت نام به پایان رسیده است  ";
                RedirectToAction("login", "Account");
                return View();

            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return View("Create");

            }
            else if (dbcontext.SettingConfs.First().offlineState == "true")
            {
                return View("Create");
            }

            else
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
```

In the first `if statement` i checked the `offlineState` if it's true i should redirect the controller to `account` controller .but it doesn't work and the mvc return My view(i.e create view) but i need to redirect to `login` action in `account` controller.Where is the problem .?

My `login view` :

```
@model EducationMVC.Models.LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ورود به سامانه";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLogin.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div id="wrapper-right">
         <div id="text-product"></div>
     </div>
    <div id="wrapper-left">
        <div id="wrapper-login">
            <div class="rows-input-login">

                <span style="font:normal 13px BYekan;color:#252525">
                    نام کاربری :
                </span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "username"})
                <div style="float:left;font:normal 11px tahoma;color:#ea0000;padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;margin-top:-85px">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rows-input-login" style="margin-top:10px;">

                <span style="font:normal 13px BYekan;color:#252525">
                    رمز عبور : 
                </span>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                <div style="float:left;font:normal 11px tahoma;color:#ea0000;padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;margin-top:-85px">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rows-input-login" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div id="row-right">
                    <div class="rows-input-login" style="height:30px;">
                        @if (TempData.ContainsKey("Message"))
                        {
                            <div class="wrapper-error" style="background: transparent; color: green">
                                @TempData["Message"]
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="row-left">
                    <input type="submit" value="ورود" class="button-caution"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rows-input-login" style="margin-top:10px;">

                @if (TempData.ContainsKey("Error"))
                {
                    <div class="wrapper-error" style="background: transparent;font-size:11px; color: #ea0000">
                        @TempData["Error"]
                    </div>
                }
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `if` condition to this, you are not reutring `RedirectToAction` you are returning `View` thats the reason View is displayed instead of redirect, For redirecting you have ti write `return RedirectToAction("Action","Controller")`:

```
if (dbcontext.SettingConfs.First().offlineState == "true")
            {

                TempData["Error"] = "ژمان ثبت نام به پایان رسیده است  ";
                return RedirectToAction("login", "Account");

            }
```

For more understanding [**Visit this link**](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4XDc110313-return-View%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToAction%28%29-vs-return-Redirect%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToRoute%28%29.html)

Comment: Thank you ehsan it works but my TempData["Error"] message doesn't appear in my login view !!when i refresh it it appears

Comment: how are you handling it in View of Login??

Comment: Yes i handle it in view of login

Comment: Ehsan sorry i made a mistake in my code .it works great .thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 RedirectToAction("login", "Account");
                return View();
```

Change it to :

```
 return RedirectToAction("login", "Account");
```

Answer (score 1):

just write:

```
return RedirectToAction("login", "Account");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("login", "Account");
```

I hope this helps